# Can I query a certain attribute of an Object right inside the parameter of the Arraylist.contains method?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of objects, I want to check if the arraylist contains an object with a certain attribute. Is it possible to do so without looping over the content?

Answer (score 1):

Depending of the type of your ArrayList and the type of the object you are using (if it is a JAVA built-in type, or an object created by you, you can use [Collections.binarySearch()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T,java.util.Comparator)) .

You need to pass the ArrayList and also a Comparator implementation, where you can create the custom code to search based on that certain attribute.

If you are using JAVA 8 or above, you can write the simplified Comparator version:

```
Comparator<YourObject> byYourAttributeComparator = (YourObject o1, YourObject o2)->o1.getYourAttribute().compareTo(o2.getYourAttribute());
Collections.binarySearch(yourList, byYourAttributeComparator);
```